# Pull variable name through to constructor on object instantiation

Tags: javascript, oop

Here's an example constructor

```
function AnObject(a, b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

and an instantiation of it

```
var example = new AnObject('test', 'test');
```

Lets say that the constructor had a property `.name`

is there anyway to build the constructor so that it sets the object's name to the name of the variable that it was instantiated with?

In the case above, the name would be `example`

-*EDIT*-

The reason I am trying to achieve this is to be as "D.R.Y" as possible.

I would like to NOT have to:

```
var example = new ObjectWithName('example');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I'm afraid that's not possible!

You see, the statement `var example = new AnObject('test', 'test');` is evaluated from right to left. So, first `new AnObject('test', 'test')` is evaluated. Then, the value it returns is assigned to `var example`.

Because of this right-to-left evaluation, there is **no way** your `AnObject` constructor can know that its return value is going to be assigned to variable `example` when it's being evaluated.

Comment: What if I `use strict` to remove the JS Hoisting issues? ( or `var example;` `example = new AnObject...` )

Comment: @Panomosh : I don't see either approach would make a difference, Neither help your constructor figure out what its return value will be assigned to.

Comment: OK, just wondered if that was a potential workaround for the "Right-to-left" :)

Comment: @Panomosh : I'm afraid there really is no workaround in this case. And yeah, I know it sucks :-p

Answer (score 1):

> is there anyway to build the constructor so that it sets the object's name to the name of the variable that it was instantiated with?

When you create a new object with

```
new AnObject('test', 'test')
```

this results in an object reference, which can be then just used directly:

```
(new AnObject("test","test")).a
```

or discarded

```
 new AnObject('test', 'test')
```

or assigned to some other object property:

```
 myotherobject["b"]=new AnObject('test', 'test')
```

or pushed into an array:

```
 myarr.push(new AnObject('test', 'test'))
```

or assigned to multiple variables at once

```
a=b=c=d=e = new AnObject('test', 'test');
```

and there is no way your constructor can know in which way the object (reference) will be used, or know the name of the variable it will be assigned to (in case of simple variable assignment).

In other words creating an object and doing something with the resulting object reference are two completely independent actions.

So unless you explicitly pass the "name" value into the constructor as the argument:

```
var example = new AnObject('example','test','test')
```

or set it later on

```
example.name="example"
```

there is no way you can achieve that.

Comment: Oh, now that I read your answer I understood the question. @Panomosh this is really impossible to do on constructor by itself.